# How to open external link in real browser instead of in-app browser in TWA

Tags: javascript, html, trusted-web-activity

Suppose I have an external link to `https://google.com` in my TWA app. I want to open that link in my android browser like chrome instead of in-app browser of TWA. How to do it?

Comment: Please give a solution

Comment: Is there any solution for that?